# Pulling / Pushing a 3D unity object using physics

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, collision, rigid-bodies

I'm making a 3D puzzle platformer game with two characters. You can switch back and forth between characters using an Input. I'm using physics to control my characters . I want my only one character to be able to push and pull blocks, and on one axis at a time (X or Z-axis). For the puzzle i'm designing, I also want the other character to stand on the block to move him to a higher ledge, but i cannot do that unless the object is kinematic. (which means the ground check isn't satisfied when the character is standing on a rigidbody)

It's also worth nothing that I made it so that the character that jumps on the block becomes a child of the object so it moves with the object.

What should I do?

I tried using the below code from the Unity API on Rigidbodies attached to the player, but still no luck.

Also supplying the ground check of my physics controller.

```
public float pushPower = 2.0f;

 void OnCollisionEnter(Collision hit)
 {
     Rigidbody body = hit.collider.attachedRigidbody;
     // no rigidbody
     if (body == null || body.isKinematic)
         return;
     // We dont want to push objects below us
     if (hit.transform.position.y < -0.3f)
         return;
     // Calculate push direction from move direction,
     // we only push objects to the sides never up and down
     Vector3 pushDir = new Vector3(hit.transform.position.x, 0, hit.transform.position.z);
     // If you know how fast your character is trying to move,
     // then you can also multiply the push velocity by that.
     // Apply the push
     body.velocity = pushDir * pushPower;
 }

        public virtual void Jump()
        {
            // conditions to do this action
            bool jumpConditions = isGrounded && !isJumping;
            // return if jumpCondigions is false
            if (!jumpConditions) return;
            // trigger jump behaviour
            jumpCounter = jumpTimer;            
            isJumping = true;
            // trigger jump animations            
            if (_rigidbody.velocity.magnitude < 1)
                animator.CrossFadeInFixedTime("Jump", 0.1f);
            else
                animator.CrossFadeInFixedTime("JumpMove", 0.2f);
        }
```

Right now using the code, the object slides away as soon as the character collides with it.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Can you try to `.normalize()` the pushDir, any maybe invert it? I think you are pushing towards the player. Also check your physics materials and try to increase pushPower.

Comment: If you're using physics to push the player character, then it's probably best to just remove your `OnCollisionEnter` and let the physics engine determine how to move the block instead of setting its velocity in code. You could [freeze the rotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-freezeRotation.html) of the block so that the block won't tip over when pushed aggressively. You may have to adjust the mass and friction of the block so that the player character's force onto the block is enough to push the block around